# Merge two different plots: one in the X-axis and the other in the Y-axis

Tags: r, normal-distribution, data-visualization, standard-deviation

I have the represented independently these two plots using R:

```
#PLOT 1
    x<-250:2500
    #Hsap. Northern European
        a<-dnorm(x,1489,167)
    #Hsap. South African
        b<-dnorm(x,1472,142)
    
    plot(x,a, type="l", lwd=3, ylim=c(0,1.2*max(a,b,c)), ylab="Probability Density", xlab="Microns")
    lines(x,b, type="l", lwd=3, col="Red")
```

[image]

## PLOT 2

```
    #CUSPAL ENAMEL FORMATION TIME
    x<-0:800
    #Hsap. Northern European
        a<-dnorm(x,447,37)
    #Hsap. South African
        b<-dnorm(x,444,33)
    
    plot(x,a, type="l", lwd=3, ylim=c(0,1.2*max(a,b,c)), ylab="Probability Density", xlab="Days")
    lines(x,b, type="l", lwd=3, col="Red")
![enter image description here][2]
```

I would like to merge both using R and obtain an image similar to that shown below. It is interesting to say that I would like as well to stand out the intervals of +- 1SD, to see the overlapping area in the two plots.
[image]

Which is the exact code in R to get into success my purpose?

UPDATE

Now, with my data I get the next figure:

[image]

As you can see, the overlapping standard deviations are not in the best place. I'd like these overlapping areas were above the normal distributions placed at the X-axis. In this way I could see clearly them.

So the question is, can you write some examples and in that way I learn how I can move these scales to avoid that situation?

In my example I would like to move upwards the right-normal distributions (Y-axis).

```
x1<-30:200
a1<-dnorm(x1,87,15)
b1<-dnorm(x1,89,13)
c1<-dnorm(x1,92,16)
d1<-dnorm(x1,104,15)

x2<-000:1600
a2<-dnorm(x2,724,66)
b2<-dnorm(x2,724,50)
d2<-dnorm(x2,835,117)

scale<-range(pretty(range(a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,d1,d2)))

remap<-function(x, to, from=range(x)) {
    (x-from[1]) / (from[2]-from[1]) * (to[2]-to[1]) + to[1] 
}

plot(NA, NA, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", type="n", xlim=scale, ylim=scale)
rect(remap(87-15, scale, range(x1)), scale[1],
     remap(87+15, scale, range(x1)), scale[2], col="#ff606025", lty=1)
rect(remap(89-13, scale, range(x1)), scale[1],
     remap(89+13, scale, range(x1)), scale[2], col="#ff606025", lty=2)
rect(remap(92-16, scale, range(x1)), scale[1],
     remap(92+16, scale, range(x1)), scale[2], col="#3dae0025", lty=0)
rect(remap(104-15, scale, range(x1)), scale[1],
     remap(104+15, scale, range(x1)), scale[2], col="#005ccd25", lty=0)

rect(scale[1], remap(724-66, scale, range(x2)),
     scale[2], remap(724+66, scale, range(x2)), col="#ff606025", lty=1)
rect(scale[1], remap(724-50, scale, range(x2)),
     scale[2], remap(724+50, scale, range(x2)), col="#ff606025", lty=2)
rect(scale[1], remap(835-117, scale, range(x2)),
     scale[2], remap(835+117, scale, range(x2)), col="#005ccd25", lty=0)

lines(remap(x1,scale), a1, col="darkred", lwd=3)
lines(remap(x1,scale), b1, col="darkred", lwd=3, lty=3)
lines(remap(x1,scale), c1, col="darkgreen", lwd=3)
lines(remap(x1,scale), d1, col="darkblue", lwd=3)

lines(scale[2]-a2, remap(x2,scale), col="darkred", lwd=3)
lines(scale[2]-b2, remap(x2,scale), col="darkred", lwd=3, lty=3)
lines(scale[2]-d2, remap(x2,scale), col="darkblue", lwd=3)


axis(2); axis(3)
axis(1, at=remap(pretty(x1), scale), pretty(x1))
axis(4, at=remap(pretty(x2), scale), pretty(x2))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky thing is each plot can only hold one coordinate system. So what we need to do are just scale all the values to the same range, then we can do some fudging on the axis to return to the correct scale. Here's a complete solution

```
x1<-250:2500
a1<-dnorm(x1,1489,167)
b1<-dnorm(x1,1472,142)

x2<-0:800
a2<-dnorm(x2,447,37)
b2<-dnorm(x2,444,33)

scale<-range(pretty(range(a1,a2,b1,b2)))

remap<-function(x, to, from=range(x)) {
    (x-from[1]) / (from[2]-from[1]) * (to[2]-to[1]) + to[1] 
}


plot(NA, NA, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", type="n", xlim=scale, ylim=scale, xlab="", ylab="")
rect(remap(1489-167, scale, range(x1)), scale[1],
    remap(1489+167, scale, range(x1)), scale[2], col=rgb(0,0,0,.25), lty=0)
rect(remap(1472-142, scale, range(x1)), scale[1],
    remap(1472+142, scale, range(x1)), scale[2], col=rgb(1,0,0,.25), lty=0)

rect(scale[1], remap(447-37, scale, range(x2)),
    scale[2], remap(447+37, scale, range(x2)), col=rgb(0,0,0,.25), lty=0)
rect(scale[1], remap(444-33, scale, range(x2)),
    scale[2], remap(444+33, scale, range(x2)), col=rgb(1,0,0,.25), lty=0)

lines(remap(x1,scale), a1, col="black", lwd=3)
lines(remap(x1,scale), b1, col="red", lwd=3)
lines(scale[2]-a2, remap(x2,scale), col="black", lwd=3)
lines(scale[2]-b2, remap(x2,scale), col="red", lwd=3)
axis(2); axis(3)
axis(1, at=remap(pretty(x1), scale, range(x1)), pretty(x1))
axis(4, at=remap(pretty(x2), scale, range(x2)), pretty(x2))
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Wow!. That is what I really wanted! Thanks so much MrFlick. Only one more thing, how can I write the name of the axis? For example Variable 1 in the botton axis and Variable 2 in the left axis?

Comment: And one more thing. Hope you can do it at the same time with my last comment, just above this one. Imagine in x1 we have other population, but in this case it is only one number, thus we don't have a sample to say that's behaves as a normal distribution. So, how is it possible to draw a vertical line, for example, with the value 1000 of the x axis?

Comment: To draw axis labels have a look at the `?title` help page and to draw straight lines look at the `?abline` help page.

Comment: My first comment was solved by myself. I only had to see the code and the the labels empty...

Comment: I will check the help page of abline. However. How can I place one point in the chart that is defined by one value of the X axis (Variable 1) and othe one from the Y axis (Variable 2). And how is possible to name it close to the point in the chart? Thanks in advacen for your help MrFlick.

Comment: I realized MrFlick that there is an important problem in the code you send me originally. If you compare where the means should be in your figure, they don't fit with mines.

The problem of the scales still continues...

How can we solve it?

Comment: There was a mistake in the axis labeling. The code has been updated.